# Shell script that open xterm, cd into a folder, run a command, and keeps me there

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to run an sh (or bash) script that cd into a folder, run a few commands and keep me there so I can start using that terminal. The problem is I can't figure out how to keep me there. the bash command at the end opens the terminal in my home folder instead of /tmp:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -hold -e "cd /tmp && ls && bash" &
```

I would like to open a few terminals like this since I am working on a project that require multiple terminals (run backend service in one, frontend dev server in the other etc..)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your command seems to work for me... No idea what might be the difference. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps there's something in one of your bash initialization files that `cd`s to your home directory?

Comment: I can even reproduce it just by typing the command in the terminal (without a bash script). I am on 16.04.2 LTS with i3 in case it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I had the following lines in my .bashrc:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd > "${HOME}/.cwd"'             # Save current working dir
[[ -f "${HOME}/.cwd" ]] && cd "$(< ${HOME}/.cwd)" # Change to saved working dir
```

The reason I have them is due to i3. I want i3 to open new terminal in the recent working dir.

I solved the issue by deleting the .cwd file:

```
xterm -e "cd /tmp && ls && rm ~/.cwd; bash" &
```